# Issue with Onclick listener inside OnItemClick listener

Tags: java, android, listview

There are very nice explanations about the OnItemclicklistener in google,but still I couldn't solve my issue.
I need to delete the items listview ,when I click any item in listview,a custom dialog box will popup with delete button and update button,when I click that delete button,It's need to delete that particular item in the listview.But now I'm getting exception on Delete button click.Please help me to solve this out.

```
rldlist3.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int position, long arg3) {

                // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
                dialog.setTitle("Manage Expenses");

                // set the custom dialog components

                Button up = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Update);
                Button del= (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Delete);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Expence row = (Expence) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        selected_id = row.getE_id();
                       System.out.println(selected_id);

                        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                        db.delete(DBhelper.TABLE3, DBhelper.ID1 + "=?", new String[]{selected_id});
                        db.close();

                        fetchData3();
                        Toast.makeText(List_activity.this, "successfully deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                });

                dialog.show();

            }

        });
```

> 10-27 09:07:16.926    1915-1915/com.example.username.weddingplanning
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.username.weddingplanning, PID: 1915
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor cannot be cast to com.example.username.weddingplanning.Expence
>               at com.example.username.weddingplanning.List_activity$1$2.onClick(List_activity.java:73)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

My expense java class

```
public class Expence {
    private String category;
    private String description;
    private String amount;
    private String date;
    private String status;
    private String year;
    private String month;

    public Expence(String e_id) {
        this.e_id = e_id;
    }

    private String e_id;

    public String getE_id() {
        return e_id;
    }

    public void setE_id(String e_id) {
        this.e_id = e_id;
    }
    //get methods to access these variables
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    //set methods to modify them
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(String month) {
        this.month = month;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and perfect solution is

```
Expence row = (Expence) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);    //This is an error
```

arg0 is an listview adapter..

Get the datas from sqlite and store it in arraylist and the set it to adapter. After done make below changes

use arraylist object in the place of arg0 like this.....

```
Expence row = (Expence) your_arraylist.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

As in Log:

> ClassCastException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor cannot be
>   cast to com.example.username.weddingplanning.Expence

Means `arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);` retruning a Cursor instead of `Expence` class object.

To get all data from Cursor to `Expence` class object first need to iterate over cursor then user setter methods for `Expence` class to prepare a required object:

```
Cursor cursor=arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
Expence row ;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        // do what you need with the cursor here
        row=new Expence(<ID>);
        row.setCategory(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Category")));
        ... Do same for other
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Actually,first I did like this `Cursor row = (Cursor) adapter.getItem( position);
                        selected_id = row.getString(0);` It gave null pointer exception,So I changed the code like this,but still I didn't understand what to do.Iterate over cursor mean?(while loop)